# Using QQ: How can I make Byobu the default terminal

Tags: 12.10, command-line, gnome-terminal, byobu

I really like the Byobu terminal better than the default Gnome terminal that is installed with Ubuntu.

How can I make Byobu the default terminal - for example, when I hit control/alt-t I'd like to see Byobu instead of the default Gnome terminal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open *Gnome Terminal*
2. Click on *Edit* -> *Profile Preferences*
3. Go to *Title and Command* tab
4. Check *Run a custom command instead of my shell*
5. Set your Custom command to

   - /usr/bin/byobu

[image]

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: That worked fine. Meanwhile I had tried another suggestion - overwrite the cntrl/alt-t with Byobu. But it didn't work. A got the warning that I'm overwriting, said OK and the hotkey was mapped to Byobu. But it doesn't work. In fact, Byobu doesn't seem to work with any keyboard shotcuts when you define them in the keyboards config applet. Any clues? BTW-good job on Byobu.

Comment: @Dustin Kirkland, is it possible to actually assign this command to run Byobu itself? The lovely icon doesn't show using this method.

Comment: @DustinKirkland is there any way to set this via the command-line? I'd like to add it to my setup scripts.

Comment: @RobinWinslow Not that I'm aware of.  Sorry.